# JavaScript Function in JSP file

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have my javascript function attached to my JSP file, however, it does not work. I got "sendMessage() does not define" error in chatPage.jsp. Please check my code and show me where did I do wrong here.

In my loginpage.jsp, I will get username and roomName, it will go through UserNameServlet, then it will getRequestDispatcher to chatpage.jsp forwarding the value of username and roomName.

This is my loginpage.jsp:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="UserNameServlet" name="submitForm" onchange="handleNewRoom()" method="GET">
            <mark>Please select a room:</mark>
            <select id="roomSelect" name="roomSelect">
                <option value="room1">Room 1</option>
                <option value="room2">Room 2</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>

            <mark>Please Enter username</mark>
            <input type="text" name="username" size="20"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my UsernameServlet

```
@WebServlet("/UserNameServlet")
public class UserNameServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     *
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @throws ServletException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        session.setAttribute("username", username);

        String roomName = request.getParameter("roomSelect");
        if("newRoomOption".equals(roomName)) roomName=request.getParameter("newRoomName");
        request.setAttribute("roomName", roomName);
        request.setAttribute("username", username);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("chatPage.jsp").forward(request,response);

        }
```

This is my chatPage.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="messagesTextArea" readonly="readonly" rows="10" cols="45"></textarea> <br>
        <input type="text" id="messagesText" size="50" /> <br>
        <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendMessage()"/>

    </body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://"+document.location.host+"+"document.location.pathname+"+""chatroomServerEndpoint/"${roomName});
            websocket.onmessage = function processMessage(message){
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(message.data);
                if(jsonData.message !== null) messagesTextArea.value += jsonData.message + "\n";
            }; 

            function sendMessage(){
                alert("hello");
            }
        </script>   
</html>
```

I have another chatRoomServerEndpoint class.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/chatroomServerEndpoint/{chatroom}", configurator=ChatroomServerConfigurator.class)
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket on the `<input/>` tag, it should read: `<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="return sendMessage();"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `input` tag of course. Looks like rest of your code is ok. If you have the

> `sendMessage()` is not defined message

— there are errors in the `sendMessage()` body or in the other parts of JavaScript code that you don't provide here. For an example, errors can be in the js files included by the `<script>` tag.

**Update**

Your scripts below the `body` element. It is incorrect.
And may be you have errors in the lines above `sendMessage()`, for an example there:  `"document.location.pathname+"+""chatroomServerEndpoint/"${roomName})`

Try to comment all those lines.

Comment: Yea, I just realise that I forgot to close the bracket, but even though, it still does not work. I am still getting the same error. When I put some basic stuff in sendMessage() like alert, it still not working.

Comment: @MinhHoangVO Is there any additional errors in the browser console? Please, update your question with the last variant of the code (with `onclick`).

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` should be used with `form element` , not with `input element`.(and you should close the input tag as mentioned in other answers.)

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
            <script type="text/javascript">            
                function sendMessage(){
                    //To do code..
                    alert('hello');
                    return false; 
                    // return false or true based on your condition/requirements
                }
            </script>       
        </head>
        <body>
            <form onsubmit="return sendMessage();">
            <textarea id="messagesTextArea" readonly="readonly" rows="10" cols="45"></textarea> <br>
            <input type="text" id="messagesText" size="50" /> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```